# Plone : Check if a form was submitted

Tags: python, forms, submit, plone

I'm working on a Plone template. Currently I'm implementing a search on the template. There is a form on the template which submits to the same template i.e. the same page.

I need to enable certain parts of the page to be viewed i.e. the results DIV, only when the form in the page has been submitted. I am not sure of how to check if a page has been submitted and display certain portions of the page.

I've looked at [this](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/forms/using-cmfformcontroller) link on using `form.submitted`, but it is really not helpful. I'm guessing whatever I have to do will be done in `tal:condition` tag.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an hidden field, name for example "submitedform" with value="1" and then, make a condition on :

```
request.get('submitedform', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work.

I used a `tal:condition` and checked for data that is inside the request object upon form submission.

To examine what is in the request object, simply put the following on your page:

```
<div tal:replace="structure request" />
```

Note: when the request object is called, it renders a readable, HTML version of the data. We use "structure" to prevent escaping the HTML.

Now, for my case, I needed to check whether my search form was submitted. So inside the DIV tag, I checked if the query string was empty or not. Below is a sample of the code:

```
<!-- Form has been submitted -->
<div tal:condition="python:request.environ.get('QUERY_STRING') != ''"></div>

<!-- Form has not been submitted -->
<div tal:condition="python:request.environ.get('QUERY_STRING') == ''"></div>
```

Note  that you can use any variable you want. I simply chose to use the `QUERY_STRING` from the request object.

This might not be perfect, but I hope it will give direction to someone else.

Comment: note that if you use a POST method for your form, then QUERY_STRING is going to be empty. Better to use a `<input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="1" /> field and test for that (`tal:condition="request/formsubmitted"`).

Comment: Potentially shorter test: `tal:condition="request/environ/QUERY_STRING"` and `tal:condition="not:request/environ/QUERY_STRING"`.